# CSS Animation carousel pause between slides

Tags: css, animation, slideshow

I have a little problem with my slideshow.
I need to have pauses of 30s between the slides, but it doesn't work (GoogleChrome and Safari). And i can use only CSS, without JS or PHP.
Can you help me? Thanks.

**Code CSS:**

```
.slide_show {

  animation-name: slideShow;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}


    @keyframes slideBg {

        0% {
            background-image: url('img/001.jpg');
        }


        33% {
            background-image: url('img/002.jpg');
        }

        66% {
            background-image: url('img/003.jpg');
        }

        100% { 
            background-image: url('img/001.jpg');  
         }
```

Comment: First of all your `animation-play-state:` has not valid value (i.e. `paused 30s, runni...`)

Comment: @Konrud 
Ok, than i can delete it.

Comment: Would an ```animation-delay: 1s;``` not give you a pause between each slide?

Comment: @StefvanStipdonk 
It's give me a pause just before first slide
And when i add it in "keyframes" after background-image: url('img/001.jpg');" nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

So, i find this solution for myself.

```
  -webkit-animation-name: slideBg;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 80s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
    @keyframes slideBg {

        0% {
            background-image: url('img/001.jpg');
        }

        30% {
            background-image: url('img/001.jpg');

        }   

        31% {
            background-image: url('img/002.jpg');   
        }
        63%
        {
            background-image: url('img/002.jpg');
        }
        66% {
            background-image: url('img/003.jpg');
        }
        97%
        {
            background-image: url('img/003.jpg');   
        }
        100% { 
            background-image: url('img/001.jpg'); 
         }
    }
```

Now thee slides stoped for ~30 sec, and within one second they change.